# Am I compiling in the wrong way?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

So I've got this RPN calculator project and I will try to post all the code for it; would I just run "C++ dc.cpp"? I get returned an error even though I know someone else has compiled it correctly. How do I compile this?

**dc.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "stack.h"
#include <string>
#include "dsexceptions.h"

using namespace std;

bool IsOperator(char op);
int calculate(char op, int operand1, int operand2);

int main() {
    string input;
    Stack<int> dc;

    while (getline(cin, input))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i<input.length(); i++)
        {
            if (input[i] == ' ')
                continue;
            else if (IsOperator(input[i]))
            {

                try {
                    int operand2 = dc.top();
                    dc.pop();

                    int operand1 = dc.top();
                    dc.pop();
                    int result = calculate(input[i], operand1, operand2);
                    dc.push(result);

                }
                catch (Underflow e) {
                    cout << "No elements in stack";

                }
                catch (Overflow e) {
                    cout << "Stack full. Can't insert more";

                }
                catch (DivisionByZero e) {
                    cout << "Please choose some other value for division except 0";

                }
                catch (InvalidOperator e) {
                    cout << "The operator you choose is invalid";
                }
            }
            else if (isdigit(input[i]))
            {
                int operand = 0;
                while (i<input.length() && isdigit(input[i]))
                {
                    operand = (operand * 10) + (input[i] - '0');
                    i++;
                }
                i--;

                if (i && input[i - 1] == '_')
                    operand *= -1;

                try {
                    dc.push(operand);
                }
                catch (Overflow e) {
                    cout << "Stack full. Can't insert more";
                }

            }
            else if (input[i] == 'p') {
                try {
                    cout << dc.top() << endl;
                }
                catch (Underflow e) {
                    cout << "No elements in stack";
                }

            }
            else if (input[i] == 'n') {
                try {
                    cout << dc.top();
                }
                catch (Underflow e) {
                    cout << "No elements in stack";
                }

            }
            else if (input[i] == 'f') {
                for (Stack <int> dump = dc; !dump.isEmpty(); dump.pop()) {

                    try {
                        cout << dump.top() << " ";
                    }
                    catch (Underflow e) {
                        cout << "No elements in stack";
                    }

                }
                cout << endl;
            }
            else if (input[i] == 'c') {
                while (!dc.isEmpty())
                    dc.pop();
            }
            else if (input[i] == 'd') {

                try {
                    dc.push(dc.top());
                }
                catch (Overflow e) {
                    cout << "Stack full. Can't insert more";
                }
                catch (Underflow e) {
                    cout << "No elements in stack";
                }


            }
            else if (input[i] == 'r') {

                try {
                    int x = dc.top();
                    dc.pop();
                    int y = dc.top();
                    dc.pop();

                    dc.push(x);
                    dc.push(y);
                }
                catch (Overflow e) {
                    cout << "Stack full. Can't insert more";
                }
                catch (Underflow e) {
                    cout << "No elements in stack";
                }
            }

        }
    }

    return 0;
}

bool IsOperator(char op)
{
    if (op == '+' || op == '-' || op == '*' || op == '/' || op == '%')
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

int calculate(char op, int operand1, int operand2)
{
    if (op == '+')
    {
        return operand1 + operand2;
    }
    else if (op == '-')
    {
        return operand1 - operand2;
    }
    else if (op == '*')
    {
        return operand1 * operand2;
    }
    else if (op == '/')
    {
        return operand1 / operand2;
        if (operand2 == 0)
        {
            throw DivisionByZero();
        }
    }
    else if (op == '%')
    {
        return operand1 % operand2;
    }

    else {
        throw InvalidOperator();
    }
}
```

**dsexceptions.h**

```
#ifndef _DSEXCEPTIONS_H_
#define _DSEXCEPTIONS_H_

#include <iostream>


class Underflow : public std::runtime_error
{
public:
    Underflow(std::string const& error)
        : std::runtime_error(error) {}

    Underflow()
        :std::runtime_error("Underflow Exception") {}
};

class Overflow : public std::runtime_error
{

public:
    Overflow(std::string const& error)
        : std::runtime_error(error) {}

    Overflow()
        :std::runtime_error("Overflow Exception") {}
};

class InvalidOperator : public std::runtime_error
{

public:
    InvalidOperator(std::string const& error)
        : std::runtime_error(error) {}

    InvalidOperator()
        :std::runtime_error("Invalid Exception") {}
};



class OutOfMemory : public std::runtime_error
{

public:
    OutOfMemory(std::string const& error)
        : std::runtime_error(error) {}

    OutOfMemory()
        :std::runtime_error("Out Of Memory Exception") {}
};

class BadIterator : public std::runtime_error
{

public:
    BadIterator(std::string const& error)
        : std::runtime_error(error) {}

    BadIterator()
        :std::runtime_error("Bad Iterator Exception") {}
};

class DataError : public std::runtime_error
{

public:
    DataError(std::string const& error)
        : std::runtime_error(error) {}

    DataError()
        :std::runtime_error("Data Error Exception") {}
};

class DivisionByZero : public std::runtime_error
{

public:
    DivisionByZero(std::string const& error)
        : std::runtime_error(error) {}

    DivisionByZero()
        :std::runtime_error("Division By Zero Exception") {}
};

#endif
```

**stack.cpp**

```
#include "dsexceptions.h"
#include "stack.h"
/**
* Construct the stack.
*/
template <class Object>
Stack<Object>::Stack(int aCapacity)
{
    topOfStack = -1;
    capacity = aCapacity;
    theArray.resize(aCapacity);
}

/**
* Test if the stack is logically empty.
* Return true if empty, false otherwise.
*/
template <class Object>
bool Stack<Object>::isEmpty() const
{
    return topOfStack == -1;
}

/**
* Test if the stack is logically full.
* Return true if full, false otherwise.
*/
template <class Object>
bool Stack<Object>::isFull() const
{
    return topOfStack == capacity - 1;
}

/**
* Make the stack logically empty.
*/
template <class Object>
void Stack<Object>::makeEmpty()
{
    topOfStack = -1;
}

/**
* Get the most recently inserted item in the stack.
* Does not alter the stack.
* Return the most recently inserted item in the stack.
* Exception Underflow if stack is already empty.
*/
template <class Object>
const Object & Stack<Object>::top() const
{
    if (isEmpty())
        throw Underflow();
    return theArray[topOfStack];
}

/**
* Remove the most recently inserted item from the stack.
* Exception Underflow if stack is already empty.
*/
template <class Object>
void Stack<Object>::pop()
{
    if (isEmpty())
        throw Underflow();
    topOfStack--;
}

/**
* Insert x into the stack, if not already full.
* Exception Overflow if stack is already full.
*/
template <class Object>
void Stack<Object>::push(const Object & x)
{
    if (isFull())
        throw Overflow();
    theArray[++topOfStack] = x;
}

/**
* Return and remove most recently inserted item from the stack.
* Return most recently inserted item.
* Exception Underflow if stack is already empty.
*/
template <class Object>
Object Stack<Object>::topAndPop()
{
    if (isEmpty())
        throw Underflow();
    return theArray[topOfStack--];
}


/* int main()
   {
       cout << "testing stack class" << endl;
       Stack<int> dc(100);
       cout << " stack class init" << endl;
       dc.push(10);

       dc.pop();
       cout << "done testing stack class" << endl;
   }*/
```

My compiler returns these errors when I run "c++ dc.cpp". I have to just be compiling it incorrectly, right?:

```
In file included from stack.cpp:1:
dsexceptions.h:8: error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token
dsexceptions.h: In constructor ‘Underflow::Underflow(const std::string&)’:
dsexceptions.h:11: error: expected class-name before ‘(’ token
dsexceptions.h:11: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘(’ token
dsexceptions.h: In constructor ‘Underflow::Underflow()’:
dsexceptions.h:14: error: expected class-name before ‘(’ token
dsexceptions.h:14: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘(’ token
dsexceptions.h: At global scope:
dsexceptions.h:18: error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token
dsexceptions.h: In constructor ‘Overflow::Overflow(const std::string&)’:
dsexceptions.h:22: error: expected class-name before ‘(’ token
dsexceptions.h:22: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘(’ token
dsexceptions.h: In constructor ‘Overflow::Overflow()’:
dsexceptions.h:25: error: expected class-name before ‘(’ token
dsexceptions.h:25: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘(’ token
dsexceptions.h: At global scope:
dsexceptions.h:29: error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token
dsexceptions.h: In constructor ‘InvalidOperator::InvalidOperator(const std::string&)’:
dsexceptions.h:33: error: expected class-name before ‘(’ token
dsexceptions.h:33: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘(’ token
dsexceptions.h: In constructor ‘InvalidOperator::InvalidOperator()’:
dsexceptions.h:36: error: expected class-name before ‘(’ token
dsexceptions.h:36: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘(’ token
dsexceptions.h: At global scope:
dsexceptions.h:42: error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token
dsexceptions.h: In constructor ‘OutOfMemory::OutOfMemory(const std::string&)’:
dsexceptions.h:46: error: expected class-name before ‘(’ token
dsexceptions.h:46: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘(’ token
dsexceptions.h: In constructor ‘OutOfMemory::OutOfMemory()’:
dsexceptions.h:49: error: expected class-name before ‘(’ token
dsexceptions.h:49: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘(’ token
dsexceptions.h: At global scope:
dsexceptions.h:53: error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token
dsexceptions.h: In constructor ‘BadIterator::BadIterator(const std::string&)’:
dsexceptions.h:57: error: expected class-name before ‘(’ token
dsexceptions.h:57: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘(’ token
dsexceptions.h: In constructor ‘BadIterator::BadIterator()’:
dsexceptions.h:60: error: expected class-name before ‘(’ token
dsexceptions.h:60: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘(’ token
dsexceptions.h: At global scope:
dsexceptions.h:64: error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token
dsexceptions.h: In constructor ‘DataError::DataError(const std::string&)’:
dsexceptions.h:68: error: expected class-name before ‘(’ token
dsexceptions.h:68: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘(’ token
dsexceptions.h: In constructor ‘DataError::DataError()’:
dsexceptions.h:71: error: expected class-name before ‘(’ token
dsexceptions.h:71: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘(’ token
dsexceptions.h: At global scope:
dsexceptions.h:75: error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token
dsexceptions.h: In constructor ‘DivisionByZero::DivisionByZero(const std::string&)’:
dsexceptions.h:79: error: expected class-name before ‘(’ token
dsexceptions.h:79: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘(’ token
dsexceptions.h: In constructor ‘DivisionByZero::DivisionByZero()’:
dsexceptions.h:82: error: expected class-name before ‘(’ token
dsexceptions.h:82: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘(’ token
In file included from stack.cpp:2:
stack.h: At global scope:
stack.h:1: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘<’ token
stack.h:34: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘vector’ with no type
stack.h:34: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘<’ token
stack.h:36: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘vector’ with no type
stack.h:36: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘<’ token
stack.cpp: In constructor ‘Stack<Object>::Stack(int)’:
stack.cpp:11: error: ‘theArray’ was not declared in this scope
stack.cpp: In member function ‘const Object& Stack<Object>::top() const’:
stack.cpp:54: error: ‘theArray’ was not declared in this scope
stack.cpp: In member function ‘void Stack<Object>::push(const Object&)’:
stack.cpp:78: error: ‘theArray’ was not declared in this scope
stack.cpp: In member function ‘Object Stack<Object>::topAndPop()’:
stack.cpp:91: error: ‘theArray’ was not declared in this scope
[jones_g@cobra Prog2]$ c++ dc.cpp
In file included from dc.cpp:2:
stack.h:1: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘<’ token
stack.h:34: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘vector’ with no type
stack.h:34: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘<’ token
stack.h:36: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘vector’ with no type
stack.h:36: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘<’ token
In file included from dc.cpp:4:
dsexceptions.h:8: error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token
dsexceptions.h: In constructor ‘Underflow::Underflow(const std::string&)’:
dsexceptions.h:11: error: expected class-name before ‘(’ token
dsexceptions.h:11: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘(’ token
dsexceptions.h: In constructor ‘Underflow::Underflow()’:
dsexceptions.h:14: error: expected class-name before ‘(’ token
dsexceptions.h:14: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘(’ token
dsexceptions.h: At global scope:
dsexceptions.h:18: error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token
dsexceptions.h: In constructor ‘Overflow::Overflow(const std::string&)’:
dsexceptions.h:22: error: expected class-name before ‘(’ token
dsexceptions.h:22: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘(’ token
dsexceptions.h: In constructor ‘Overflow::Overflow()’:
dsexceptions.h:25: error: expected class-name before ‘(’ token
dsexceptions.h:25: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘(’ token
dsexceptions.h: At global scope:
dsexceptions.h:29: error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token
dsexceptions.h: In constructor ‘InvalidOperator::InvalidOperator(const std::string&)’:
dsexceptions.h:33: error: expected class-name before ‘(’ token
dsexceptions.h:33: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘(’ token
dsexceptions.h: In constructor ‘InvalidOperator::InvalidOperator()’:
dsexceptions.h:36: error: expected class-name before ‘(’ token
dsexceptions.h:36: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘(’ token
dsexceptions.h: At global scope:
dsexceptions.h:42: error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token
dsexceptions.h: In constructor ‘OutOfMemory::OutOfMemory(const std::string&)’:
dsexceptions.h:46: error: expected class-name before ‘(’ token
dsexceptions.h:46: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘(’ token
dsexceptions.h: In constructor ‘OutOfMemory::OutOfMemory()’:
dsexceptions.h:49: error: expected class-name before ‘(’ token
dsexceptions.h:49: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘(’ token
dsexceptions.h: At global scope:
dsexceptions.h:53: error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token
dsexceptions.h: In constructor ‘BadIterator::BadIterator(const std::string&)’:
dsexceptions.h:57: error: expected class-name before ‘(’ token
dsexceptions.h:57: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘(’ token
dsexceptions.h: In constructor ‘BadIterator::BadIterator()’:
dsexceptions.h:60: error: expected class-name before ‘(’ token
dsexceptions.h:60: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘(’ token
dsexceptions.h: At global scope:
dsexceptions.h:64: error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token
dsexceptions.h: In constructor ‘DataError::DataError(const std::string&)’:
dsexceptions.h:68: error: expected class-name before ‘(’ token
dsexceptions.h:68: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘(’ token
dsexceptions.h: In constructor ‘DataError::DataError()’:
dsexceptions.h:71: error: expected class-name before ‘(’ token
dsexceptions.h:71: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘(’ token
dsexceptions.h: At global scope:
dsexceptions.h:75: error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token
dsexceptions.h: In constructor ‘DivisionByZero::DivisionByZero(const std::string&)’:
dsexceptions.h:79: error: expected class-name before ‘(’ token
dsexceptions.h:79: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘(’ token
dsexceptions.h: In constructor ‘DivisionByZero::DivisionByZero()’:
dsexceptions.h:82: error: expected class-name before ‘(’ token
dsexceptions.h:82: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘(’ token
[jones_g@cobra Prog2]$ c++ dc.cpp
In file included from dc.cpp:2:
stack.h:1: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘<’ token
stack.h:34: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘vector’ with no type
stack.h:34: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘<’ token
stack.h:36: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘vector’ with no type
stack.h:36: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘<’ token
In file included from dc.cpp:4:
dsexceptions.h:8: error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token
dsexceptions.h: In constructor ‘Underflow::Underflow(const std::string&)’:
dsexceptions.h:11: error: expected class-name before ‘(’ token
dsexceptions.h:11: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘(’ token
dsexceptions.h: In constructor ‘Underflow::Underflow()’:
dsexceptions.h:14: error: expected class-name before ‘(’ token
dsexceptions.h:14: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘(’ token
dsexceptions.h: At global scope:
dsexceptions.h:18: error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token
dsexceptions.h: In constructor ‘Overflow::Overflow(const std::string&)’:
dsexceptions.h:22: error: expected class-name before ‘(’ token
dsexceptions.h:22: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘(’ token
dsexceptions.h: In constructor ‘Overflow::Overflow()’:
dsexceptions.h:25: error: expected class-name before ‘(’ token
dsexceptions.h:25: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘(’ token
dsexceptions.h: At global scope:
dsexceptions.h:29: error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token
dsexceptions.h: In constructor ‘InvalidOperator::InvalidOperator(const std::string&)’:
dsexceptions.h:33: error: expected class-name before ‘(’ token
dsexceptions.h:33: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘(’ token
dsexceptions.h: In constructor ‘InvalidOperator::InvalidOperator()’:
dsexceptions.h:36: error: expected class-name before ‘(’ token
dsexceptions.h:36: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘(’ token
dsexceptions.h: At global scope:
dsexceptions.h:42: error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token
dsexceptions.h: In constructor ‘OutOfMemory::OutOfMemory(const std::string&)’:
dsexceptions.h:46: error: expected class-name before ‘(’ token
dsexceptions.h:46: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘(’ token
dsexceptions.h: In constructor ‘OutOfMemory::OutOfMemory()’:
dsexceptions.h:49: error: expected class-name before ‘(’ token
dsexceptions.h:49: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘(’ token
dsexceptions.h: At global scope:
dsexceptions.h:53: error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token
dsexceptions.h: In constructor ‘BadIterator::BadIterator(const std::string&)’:
dsexceptions.h:57: error: expected class-name before ‘(’ token
dsexceptions.h:57: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘(’ token
dsexceptions.h: In constructor ‘BadIterator::BadIterator()’:
dsexceptions.h:60: error: expected class-name before ‘(’ token
dsexceptions.h:60: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘(’ token
dsexceptions.h: At global scope:
dsexceptions.h:64: error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token
dsexceptions.h: In constructor ‘DataError::DataError(const std::string&)’:
dsexceptions.h:68: error: expected class-name before ‘(’ token
dsexceptions.h:68: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘(’ token
dsexceptions.h: In constructor ‘DataError::DataError()’:
dsexceptions.h:71: error: expected class-name before ‘(’ token
dsexceptions.h:71: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘(’ token
dsexceptions.h: At global scope:
dsexceptions.h:75: error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token
dsexceptions.h: In constructor ‘DivisionByZero::DivisionByZero(const std::string&)’:
dsexceptions.h:79: error: expected class-name before ‘(’ token
dsexceptions.h:79: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘(’ token
dsexceptions.h: In constructor ‘DivisionByZero::DivisionByZero()’:
dsexceptions.h:82: error: expected class-name before ‘(’ token
dsexceptions.h:82: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘(’ token
```

Comment: I should also mention-- everything was fine before I implemented error handling.

Comment: Can you post your stack.h file? I think you're probably missing a semicolon there.

Comment: which operating system, compiler and which versions are you using? How exactly have you compiled your code (I recommend a *recent* [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) with `g++ -Wall -g` ....)

Comment: No, you are not compiling incorrectly.   The code you are compiling is flawed.   The fact it has compiled previously, presumably with another compiler or version of the compiler, is blind luck.

Comment: Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Comment: 1. Get qmake. 2. In your project folder, call qmake -project, qmake -makefile, make. 3. Be happy. 4. Make sure to look at the project file and the makefile some time to learn how they work so that you are able to create them by yourself at some point in time and also to edit them.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are compiling it fine, but your code has errors, which your compiler is telling you about.

At the very least, add...

```
#include <stdexcept>
```

... to your dsexceptions.h file.

You might also need to add...

```
#include <vector>
```

... to your stack.h file.

Comment: This is not an answer. An ok comment, but not an ok answer.

Comment: I think with the wall-of-text errors, it's a reasonable answer. Obviously, the problem is the OP has not included the appropriate headers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the error message more carefully.  Taking just the first message:

> ```
> dsexceptions.h:8: error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token
> ```

You can see that the compiler doesn't recognise the token immediately preceding `{`.  What's that token?  Line 7 is

```c++
class Underflow : public std::runtime_error
```

Yes, you're using `std::runtime_error`, but haven't defined it.  The fix, of course, is to `#include <stdexcept>` instead of the unnecessary `#include <iostream>`.

In your headers you should normally include any definitions that the header needs (and only what the header needs).  If you don't, then you are likely to end up with very fragile code where headers fail as above if the code using them doesn't know the prerequisites.  It's okay to include the standard library headers multiple times, and the same is true of any well-written library header.

There are tools, such as `include-what-you-use` (aka `iwyu`) to help analyse your source files for missing or unnecessary includes - you should certainly look to see if that might help you.